# Hi i want make Container Radius what is the best way to add radius to conatainer?

Tags: flutter

i wanna add radius to container how to add radius to container?
when i try to add decoration to container its does not showing up.

```
 Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              decoration: kBoxDecorationStyle,
              height: 60,
              child: TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'OpenSans'),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                      Icons.email,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    hintText: 'Enter your Email',
                    hintStyle: kHintTextStyle),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use decoration propery of Container:

```
       Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 60,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            color: Colors.amber,
          ),
          child: Center(child: Text('Radius')),
        ),
```

But remember, you must use color property in the decoration if you add decoration property to a Container.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Different ways you can choose which one suits you

```
Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
```

or

```
  ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Great thank you. its helps a lots to me